# Changing device volume completely disables it

Tags: windows-10, audio, drivers, volume-mixer, realtek-hd-audio

I am having an issue on my pc (is a new computer) when I change the "Device" Speakers volume in volume mixer - speakers.

Changing any of the other sliders for other programs is no problem, but once I change the first slider, the volume just shuts off.

I thought this was a driver issue, so I went to device manager and uninstalled the "Realtek High Definition Audio" Driver. I then restarted my pc, and the audio worked fine, until I changed the slider. The issue occurred again. I'm confused at this point, so I decide to look at the realtek driver version on my other computer, which was 6.0.1.8569.

The computer with the issue is 6.0.1.7910.

To me, this seems outdated. I update the driver, and press "search automatically", and it says that the best drivers are already installed.

I even search online for the same version my other computer has, and I download it. I click update and click "Browse my computer for driver software", and where it shows "choose directory" for the new driver, I choose downloads (that being where it is), and on the next page, it says "The best drivers for your device are already installed".

How can I get my volume back?

Specs:
Windows 10 Home (Unactivated product license)
AMD Ryzen 3 2200g

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnJ2e.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this got solved, but I unplugged my headphone jack from the front panel, and plugged it into the back io port on my motherboard. This "Asus Realtek Audio Manager" popped up and asked for what I plugged in. I played a video, hoping to hear something, but still nothing.

I decided that it was no use to continue this pointless troubleshooting. I don't know why, but I plugged my headphones back into the front. The same window popped up, and I almost decided to ignore it, but I answered its questions, and then heard some faint noises coming from the earpods. I put them on, and the audio was working fine.

So I guess plugging things in and out can help. I suppose that the audio drivers wern't exactly detecting that the headphones were plugged in this entire time.